# No funciona login en Server

Tags: php, login, session

Cree una aplicacion web con la combinacion de html,css,javascript,ajax y php
En mi localhost funciona perfectamente, pero al subirlo al servidor el servidor no se muestra correctamente.
Mi login no funciona, me muestra lo siguiente :***This page isn’t working website.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500***

La version de PHP es la misma en XAMPP y mi server

Mi codigo es sencillo, solo valida que exista el usuario y que coincida la contraseña que se envio previamente

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  require('/Conexion/conexionP.php');
  $Usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
  $Pass=$_POST['pass'];
  $result=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT idUsuarios FROM usuarios WHERE email=? AND pass=? AND activo!=0 LIMIT 1");
  $result->bind_param("ss",$Usuario,$Pass);
  $result->execute();
  $result->bind_result($idUsuarios);
  $result->store_result();
  if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
      $result->fetch();
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['usuario']=$Usuario;
      $_SESSION['autor']=$idUsuarios;
      $autor=$_SESSION['autor'];
      $result->close();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='menu.php';</script>";

  }
  else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
  }
}
else {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
}
```

Comment: No es recomendado pero, habilita el `display error` de php de tu servidor, así tendrás una descripción del error. Otra opción mas viable es ver si el log de tu servidor se encuentra activo y capturo el error. En cuanto obtengas esto regresa y plasma el error aca.

Comment: No tengo acceso a la configuracion del servidor. Hay alguna forma de mostrar los errores de php por e codigo? Agregue error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); pero no me muestra nada